# I am using chart.js I sent my time values throw my api as timestamp know i need to show them in the chart as date format

Tags: javascript, python, time, timestamp, chart.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
       labels: {{ labels}},//labels are the time values                         
       datasets: [{
           label: '# temperature',
           data: {{ datas}},
           backgroundColor: [
               'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
           ],
           borderColor: [
               'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
           ],
           borderWidth: 1
       }]
   },
   options: {
       scales: {
           yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                   beginAtZero: true
               }
           }]

       }
   }
});
```

Comment: First, please formulate a clear question. Describe the expected result and the problem you're facing obtaining it. Then also provide a sample of the base data you're trying to show  in the chart.

Comment: @uminder datas contains a list of time it looks like this `[1585725538000, 1585725661000, 1585729616000, 1585729629000, 1585729655000, 1585729866000, 1585842424000, 1585842498000, 1585842536000, 1585938521000, 1585938665000, 1585938685000] ` so when it's displayed in the shart the axis takes values like 1585725538000 but what i wanna do is to convert 1585725538000 into 2020-04-01 09:18:58 I hope it's clear

Comment: I understand that the time data you show needs to be represented on the `xAxis`. What about the corresponding values that should appear on the `yAxis`, how do they look like?

Comment: yAxis representes Values of temperature Xaxis represnts time , I succeeded to display the chart but the only problem is that the values that shows in the xAxis are in timestamp format like this 1585725538000 what i want to do is to convert them into date formate like this 2020-04-01 09:18:58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) with a unit that matches your data. The default [display format](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) of 'hour' is 'hA' (for instance '2PM'). You should probably also use the same format for displaying tooltips.

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    unit: 'hour',
    tooltipFormat: 'hA' 
  }
}],
```

> Please note that Chart.js uses Moment.js for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

Please have a look at belo runnable code snippet.

```js
const labels = [1585725538000, 1585729616000, 1585742414000, 1585812498000, 1585842536000, 1585918521000, 1585938665000, 1585948685000];
const datas = [15, 16, 15, 17, 12, 13, 11, 12];

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: '# temperature',
      data: datas,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour',
          tooltipFormat: 'hA' 
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> 
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you a lot that worked perfectly , I have some questions if you can answer me i would be so grateful , first the datetime.utcnow() gives me a dete with 1hour+ how can i manage to make it as the time in my time zone ,second in the unit and tooltipFormat do i can concatinate 2 formates for example 'week hour' ?

Comment: @Ghait: Me or someone else will be glad to answer your new questions. You shoud however not chain them in the same thread. If you think my answer was the solution to your original question, please mark it as 'accepted' and post new questions for the new issues.